# How to check if checkbox is checked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checked

I need to make 5 checkbox which all have a value, going from 1 to 5, I need to print out in a textbox the value when I check one, I can uncheck the boxes and the number disappears.. My problem lies in the uncheck part, I can't seem to find a way to remove the value from the textbox when it's unchecked.. I tried

```
if( aInput[0].checked == false){

    aTxt[0].value = aInput[0].value;

}
```

But it dosen't work

Comment: can you provide your entire code dealing with the writing of text to your textbox please

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="1" id = "R36" name="radio" onClick="textbox.value += this.value + ', '"/>

This is the method I used to print the values in the textbox

Comment: In this case you might want to write `<input type="checkbox" value="1" id = "R36" name="radio" onClick="textbox.value += (this.checked ? this.value : '0') + ', '"/>` - If you want your checkbox to be initially checked, use the `checked` attribute: `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

Answer (score 7):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox), the result of getting the value property of a checkbox will **always** be the string "on" or another value that you specified elsewhere. It **won't change** when you check or uncheck the box.

Thus, the textbox's value will always be set to the same value.

See for yourself:

```js
checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(checkbox.checked, checkbox.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

You need to modify your code, e.g. as follows:

```
if (aInput[0].checked) {
    aTxt[0].value = aInput[0].value;
} else {
    aTxt[0].value = ''; // define a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's not checked, set the text box to an empty string:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aInput.length; i++) {
    if (aInput[i].checked) {
        aTxt[i] = aInput[i].value;
    } else {
        aTxt[i] = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < aInput.length; i++)
   if(!aInput[i].checked){
      aTxt[i].value = '';
   }
}
```

the `code` above will basically set the value of that particular `textbox` to an empty `string` if it is not `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the value of the textbox to *zero* or *empty*

```
if( aInput[0].checked == false){

aTxt[0].value = "";

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", DoSomething);


function  DoSomething(){
     if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML+=$(this).val();
     }
     else{
     var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
     text=  text.replace($(this).val(),'');
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
     }
          
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="help_text" value="1" />

<input type="checkbox" name="help_text" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="help_text" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="help_text" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="help_text" value="5" />
</form>
<div id="text"></div>
```

I did use jquery, but you can write it in pure js also

Answer (score -1):

The problem is I need to be able to show all the numbers at once, for exemple : 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,3,5 or 1,2,5 , etc..